# Selenium Grid - Unable to find elements on the 2nd page in IE11

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, iedriverserver

I have some selenium tests that work great in `Chrome` (locally and remotely) but when I run them remotely from my machine to a Windows 2012 VM they can't find any elements **AFTER** clicking a button to move to the next web page.

Here is a code snippet:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = null;
caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8);
String nodeURL = "http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub"
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), caps);

// IE launches correctly, goes the cart page.  Calculations are done on the pricing, and we click to move to the login page

driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("test@test.com"); 
// ^^ NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == userName
```

So obviously there is a good connection made. Actions are performed and my tests move from the cart page to the login page. I even added a `wait.until`, hoping that it was a timing issue, but it timed out after 15 seconds. I'm watching the driver on RDP, it moved to the page. During the 15 seconds, I even opened the dev tools and checked to see if the element was there and it was.

What's going on?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the page is done loading by the time you start searching for it?

Comment: Absolutely sure.  I added a 15 timeout to be sure.  It's not a huge page , just a login intercept for an commerce site.  Add a username/password, or continue as guest.  Neither button works in IE.

Comment: Can you include your explicit wait statements in your code? Also, out of curiosity, have you tried it with Firefox or Edge?

Comment: I figured out what the issue is...see my answer for the annoying solution.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: As a QA automation engineer, I hate IE.

It turns out that http://company.com was added a trusted site, but not http**s**://company.com.  Once I added that, it started working.

Did I mention I hate IE?